# Refer to only 1 button (to the effect of $(this) ) when calling $("button")?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a todo web app right now that stores everything the user types in when they press enter. So when enter is pressed, it stores a todo, in the form of an < li > tag.

I'm making a delete functionality through a button that appears, and I try to add a trash icon to the buttons, which appear when I hover over the button. Whenever I add the trash icon to a newly made todo that I created, the event of adding the trash icon to the button does the same even for buttons before it. How do I prevent this from triggering past buttons?

I know using $("button") triggers all of the buttons, but how do I select only the target one?

[my code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9T2kB.png)
[the resulting error that occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKs3W.png)

As you can see, there are now 4 trashcans on the first delete button, 3 on the second, 2 on the third, and only 1 on the fourth. There should only be 1 trash icon, but it doesn't work because I'm sure $("button") refers to all of the buttons, but I don't know how to refer to only the target button (instead of all the previous buttons).

I'm looking for a keypress, and whenever it hits enter, a new todo is created, correct? As I am creating that

todo element, I'm also trying to create and append a trash button to the right side. I need to wrap the icon to the button, but when I execute that line of code, it wraps the icon to EVERY existing button, even though some buttons already have the icon. How do I change this so that the icons are only created once for each button.

Comment: post your code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the selector some context, for instance a parent element or container:

```
$('button', li);
```

or

```
$(li).find('button')
```

---

That said, isn't your button just the `trash`? `$(trash)` may be enough

Comment: Wow, $(trash) was enough... I recall myself trying just "trash.wrapInner" and it didn't work, but that's because I probably forgot $()... this was bugging me all day, but finally, thanks!

Comment: @JWong if using jQuery why even create elements this way?  If you're going to use jQuery, you might as well use it more.

Comment: I'm still learning the basics of it, trying to implement it as I learn and go along.

Answer (score 0):

Try `$(trash)`. You can create jQuery instance with HTMLDOMElement.

More information - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/